# simplicial nomenclature and homology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-complexes

Suppose I have a simplicial complex $K$ constructed by taking two simplicial complexes $K_1$ and $K_2,$ and coning off ever vertex of $K_1$ to all of $K_2$ and vice versa (so, a direct generalization of a complete bipartite graph and also of a suspension). The questions are:

1. What is this called?
2. What is the homology of this object?

Comment: Is it the join?

Comment: @MarkGrant I looked in three different places, and got three different definitions :) So, I am not sure.

Comment: I had in mind the definition given eg here: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Join. But what you have seems to be a subcomplex of it.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Might be homotopic, I guess.